# (WebDev using MVC/C#) How to associate a .mdf file on App_Data folder with an already existing DB?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Hello dear developers,

I'll explain my scenario;
I'm trying to use a scheduler sample named dhtmlx.
It uses two core items: a .mdf file placed in the App_Data folder and a .dbml file (LINQ related) placed in the Models folder.

Now, what I'm trying to accomplish: all of this works if I create a new .mdf file and when I start adding, editing and deleting events, it works.
In my case, I want to use an already existing DB which I created on SQL Server.
Both have the same exact structure, I just want to know how I can access the already existing DB that I made.

Can any of you help me out with this matter?
Thanks in advance for reading.

Comment: Does it give you any errors at all? Are you using DB Migrations by chance?

Comment: Nope, I don't get any errors if I use a new .mdf file created on Visual Studio. I just want to know how I can have a .mdf file which allows me to work with my existing DB. I already tried to change the .mdf file connection to my DB file but I can't manipulate data there.